# Portable alternative to `script(1)`

Tags: shell-script

When I have to produce a log of a tool that responds to interactive input on the terminal (tee on stdout breaks this somehow), I reach for the `script(1)` tool, and it works more or less as advertised. Unfortunately, `script` takes different options on Linux compared to Mac (presumably a BSD version?).

I'd like to make use of `script`-like functionality in a portable script. What other tool can accomplish something similar (perhaps GNU `screen`)?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with these unnamed non-standard options? (What non-standard option is it that you want?)

Comment: Depends what you mean by "portable". Most systems have a `script` command with a common feature set API and then some divergences. Few have GNU screen or tmux installed. GNU screen can be installed on most systems. If it's a zsh script you're writing, see its `zpty` module and builtin.

Comment: `script filename command...` (Mac) vs. `script -c "command..." filename` (Debian) seems like it might be a relevant difference. But I seem to have `screen` on Mac already, and getting it on Linux should be trivial. Just needs the appropriate screenrc file or options to start the program and enable logging

Comment: @ChrisDavies That's a good question. I find many of the options quite useful, such as the setting logging to flush in realtime and timing information.

I was hoping to find a tool performing this task that I can reasonably install on Linux and Mac and expect to have the same functionality and flags. I used to grudgingly wrap all my non-portable tools with binary detection like your answer below, but I've grown tired of managing inconsistent CLI options and I've been (mostly successfuly) standardising my toolkit to only use tools that I can install on both platforms with identical options.

Comment: @ChrisDavies I do pretty much what you suggest e.g. installing and using GNU everywhere. That's one of the issues with `script(1)`; for whatever reason, the `script(1)` does not appear to have builds for Mac, or vice versa. I've read that script (provided by util-linux, distributed by the Linux Kernel Organization) couldn't be built for other platforms (I think it was something to do with the syscalls used?). A subset of util-linux is indeed usable on other platforms like Mac, but it doesn't include script.

Comment: No worries, any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you across both Linux-based and FreeBSD/macos platforms:

```
myscript() {
    if script --help >/dev/null 2>&1
    then
        SHELL=/bin/sh script -c "$2" -- "$1"
    else
        script -- "$1" /bin/sh -c -- "$2"
    fi
}
```

Usage

```
myscript <file> <sh-code>
```

You'll need to quote the command component if it is anything other than a trivial command. For example,

```
myscript myfile 'a=$(date); echo "Today is $a"'
```

Comment: If `script` is not runnable for some reason (not there, pathing, permissions etc) this would still attempt to run the `else`.

Comment: @bxm indeed it would. And it would fail there too. I don't think a portability function like this needs to worry about that - I would expect the main script to have checked that `script` existed in some form before even attempting to use it. But you can always add a third `if` branch if you'd like to use `if type script >/dev/null 2>&1; then #script exists#; else #error#; fi`

Comment: NetBSD's and OpenBSD's do `script -c sh-code` (not `--help`). The original implementation in 3BSD had `-S` to specify the shell but no way to pass a command line. That `-S` was removed in 1982 on BSDs. The ability to add a command in FreeBSD script was added in Dec 1997 (first included in FreeBSD 3.0.0).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas given how old some of the tools are on the Mac I had to check that it even had a _command_ option. (I should have checked it was/was not passed through a shell though. Missed that.)

Comment: Note that man.freebsd.org now [has macOS man pages](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=script&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=macOS+13.5&arch=default&format=html)